# How can i make my Hippo CMS template full width?

Tags: angular, content-management-system, angular-ui-bootstrap, hippocms

I'm having some problems to create my template in hippo CMS. I'm trying to give the template a full width but with my navigator I found that somewhere there's a `col-sm-9` that makes the view horrible. Here you have an image: 
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvXjO.png)

And there's the part of code where Hippo is using Bootstrap to make that `col-sm-9`:
[Image link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLFhj.png)

So, my question is, where can I change that to make that width 100%?

Thanks to everyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

That class has to be on a template somewhere in your project. Find the template, change the class. This is something contributed by essentials?

Comment: I found it bro! Finally I needed to modify it in the project at the main classes. Thanks anyway!!! ;DD

Comment: Glad you found it.